# Distinct() doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct

I have the following linq expression:

```
AgentsFilter = new BindableCollection<NameValueGuid>((
    from firstEntry in FirstEntries
    select new NameValueGuid { 
        Name = firstEntry.Agent,
        Value = firstEntry.AgentId
    }).Distinct()
);
```

But because of some reason, the AgentsFilter Collection is full of duplicates. What is wrong with my `Distinct()`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Distinct` will use the `Equals` method on `NameValueGuid` to find duplicates.  IF you do not override `Equals`, then it will check references.

You can add an extra step to avoid overriding Equals, by using an anonymous type.  Anonymous types automatically override Equals and GetHashCode to compare each member.  Doing the distinct on the anonymous type, then projecting that onto your class will solve the problem.

```
from firstEntry in FirstEntries
select new
{ 
    Name = firstEntry.Agent,
    Value = firstEntry.AgentId
}).Distinct().Select(x => new NameValueGuid
{
    Name = x.Name,
    Value = x.Value
});
```

Comment: Thank you and all others who answered.

Comment: Vote up for 'Distinct will use the Equals method to find duplicates. If you do not override Equals, then it will check references'.

Comment: just to clarify this part: "IF you do not override Equals, then it will check references" -- it should read "IF you do not override Equals *and* *GetHashCode*, then it will check references"; overriding `Equals` alone isn't enough (or at least wasn't for me)

Answer (score 10):

You might not have supplied an implementation of both `GetHashCode` and `Equals` on `NameValueGuid`.

Alternatively, if that isn't possible, you can pass an instance of `IEqualityComparer<NameValueGuid>` to your call of `Distinct`.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx

Comment: Good explanation, but there is another solution: using anonymous types (see *Cadrell0*'s answer)

Comment: +1, Didn't realize I needed to override `GetHashCode` as well for `Distinct` to work. After overriding it, it appears that `Distinct` first calls `GetHashCode` to determine whether it needs to call `Equals`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define what `Distinct` means in the context of a class with `Name` and `Value` properties. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx).

Try the overload of Distinct that lets you provide a comparer.

For example:

```
AgentsFilter = new BindableCollection<NameValueGuid>((from firstEntry in FirstEntries
    select new NameValueGuid
    { 
        Name = firstEntry.Agent,
        Value = firstEntry.AgentId
    })
    .Distinct((nvg) => nvg.Value)
);
```

Alternatively, if you have access to the code definition of NameValueGuid, then you can override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` as appropriate for the class. Again, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
select new
{ 
    Name = firstEntry.Agent,
    Value = firstEntry.AgentId
})
.Distinct()
.Select(x => new NameValueGuid
{
    Name = x.Name,
    Value = x.Value
});
```